# What is the specification of the Visio functions _ELLIPSE_ECC and _ELLIPSE_THETA

Tags: visio

I'm trying to implement an application that is able to paint Visio shapes (that are read from Visio XML files). My problem is that Visio typically uses the internal functions _ELLIPSE_ECC and _ELLIPSE_THETA for the C and D cells of EllipticalArcTo. In the MSDN Visio SDK doc, I found only the following information (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff767234.aspx):

> Certain functions appear in formulas generated by Visio, but are not
>   listed in the Insert Function dialog box or described in this
>   reference because they are reserved for internal use and should not be
>   used in other formulas. Following are examples: ELLIPSE_THETA,
>   _ELLIPSE_ECC, _UCON_C1, and _SHAPEMIN.

I tried to use the pre-calculated value from the file instead of the formula but that works only well if the aspect ratio of a shape is not changed.

Does anybody know there to find more information about these functions?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this thread at Visio Guy's forum.
http://visguy.com/vgforum/index.php?topic=880.msg3907#msg3907

The Visio Guy forum is run by Microsoft Visio MVP Chris Roth who was one of the original shape masters at Visio Corporation.

Comment: I don't see how this thread is related to my question? I know how to draw an elliptical arc if all of its parameters are specified. The problem is that in a typical Visio XML file, the C and D parameter of EllipticalArcTo are given by formulas which contain the unspecified internal functions. So I need to calculate the values of these functions before I can calculate the arc.